# view count increase in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to increase the view count with 1 on each refresh. I'm not sure about the method since I'm new to DRF. Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

serializers.py

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class ModuleView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Module.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModuleSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        obj = self.get_object
        print(obj)
        obj.view_count = obj.view_count + 1
        obj.save(view_count="view_count")
        return super().get(request)
```

Comment: You can just do `obj.save()`, you can optimise it by `obj.save(update_fields=['view_count'])` if no other fields are effected. Also `get_object` is a method, you have to call it with parentheses `get_object()`

Answer (score 0):

i implemented view count with F expression because a view count is basicly a race condidition and the docs clearly state that

> Avoiding race conditions using F()

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

Comment: While you suggest a good practice, it would be more helpful to provide some example code snippets using OP's `Module` model.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ElonDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
queryset = Elon.objects.all()
serializer_class = ElonDetailSerializer
lookup_field = 'slug'
```

#retrieve

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    print(obj)
    obj.view = obj.view + 1
    obj.save(update_fields=['view',])
    serializer = self.get_serializer(obj)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

here i used RetrieveAPIView